# Elasticsearch - query_string, _all fields, lower score for particular field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to lower the score for matches in one field in a `query_string` search with the `default_field` set to `_all`. Any help would be appreciated!

My current query looks something like this (assuming the user entered two keywords, foo and bar):

`{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "analyzer":"whitespace",
                  "default_field":"_all",
                  "query":"foo~ AND bar~"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}`

Assuming some data like this:

`{
   prop: 'foo is here',
   prop2: 'bar is there',
   lessImportant: ''
},
{
   prop: '',
   prop2: 'foo is bar',
   lessImportant: ''
},
{
   prop: '',
   prop2: '',
   lessImportant: 'bar is foo'
}`

I need a way to make sure that documents that have a match in `lessImportant` have a lower score than matches in other fields, so that #2 is always returned before #3.

Comment: Can you share your query DSL and desired output? It will help us to understand your question.

Comment: I've revised my question.